# Reading directory's contents using Javascript

Tags: javascript, file, directory, fileapi

I have a single text input box where user enters a path to a directory. I want to fetch names of all the files from that directory using File API in JavaScript.

I was reading from this article: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/#toc-dir and tried executing the code under **Reading a Directory's contents** but was unable to understand the code since we are mentioning the directory name anywhere in the code.

So, how can i accomplish my task?

Answer (score 0):

As far as the **SPECS** are concerned,

It is not possible to read normal file system directories from the browser apart from the upload button / flash etc.

The browser can, however create a sandbox (in its user files) which appears as a directory structure you can manipulate. This is useful for apps that need to play with actual files and store them locally rather than on server.

**Real Life story**

The filesystem API is not supported, rather dead specs which may find its way to implementation if need arise.
Nearest currently working functionality is [local storage](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html)